# How to store MPMediaLibrary lastModifiedDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsobject

I'm writing an app based on the `MPMediaLibrary`. I'm checking, whether the `lastModifiedDate` changed and modify my data correspondingly.

What I'm wondering is, how I should store the date? I'm using `CoreData` for the rest of my data. So it would make sense, to store it there. On the other hand, I'd need to create a whole new entity. I could also store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

Which one should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Using Core Data for this seems heavy, `NSUserDefaults` is probably your best bet.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:[[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] lastModifiedDate] forKey:@"lastModifiedDate"];
```

Comment: Thats what I think. On the other hand I'm heavily using CoreData. So I would store data in different places.

Comment: @Dimitri It sounds like you know what you want to use.